# Splitting .tiff with Python PIL -> OSError 24: Too many open Files

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I am trying to split and save dual page .tiff files.
I want to save the first Page of the in directory A and the second on directory B.
After around 4000 (always different Nr. of completed Files),images I get the "OSError 24: Too many open files".
Please note that the error appears in the .save() method.

```
for file in os.listdir(path): #path is directory as str

filename = os.fsdecode(file)

with Image.open(path + "/" + filename) as img:

    for i, frame in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(img)):
        #pass
        if i: frame.save("C:/Users/kf/Desktop/Page2_/" + filename)
        else: frame.save("C:/Users/kf/Desktop/Page1_/" + filename) # error always in this line
```

So I tried:

- increasing max open files -> same Problem after around 4000 images
- saving the image in a variable after .open() -> same Problem after around 8000 images
- without "with - as" but .open() and .close() -> same problem
- comment out both lines in last for-loop and uncomment pass -> works fine

So can anybody help me out? I Have to split 30000 images.

Comment: Sounds like a bug somewhere in the libraries you're using that leaves handles open...

Comment: so there's basiclly nothing i can do right? I thought about splitting the pictures in 10 folders and let the program run 10 times. This should work

Comment: Well, aside from tracking down and fixing the bug, you could use `multiprocessing` with `maxtasksperchild` set low enough, so the leaks are closed by the multiprocesses shutting down...

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment: assuming this is a bug somewhere in PIL that has it leak handles, you could sidestep that by using `multiprocessing`:

```
path = ...


def process_file(filename):
    with Image.open(path + "/" + filename) as img:
        for i, frame in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(img)):
            if i:
                frame.save("C:/Users/kf/Desktop/Page2_/" + filename)
            else:
                frame.save("C:/Users/kf/Desktop/Page1_/" + filename)
    print("Processed", file)


def main():
    filenames = [os.fsdecode(file) for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith(".tiff")]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(maxtasksperchild=10) as p:
        for _ in p.imap_unordered(process_file, filenames):
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Excellent idea for a work-around!

Answer (score 0):

You already have an excellent suggestion from @AKX, but I thought this might also be an option. Basically, I assume it is unlikely to be the Python Standard Library leaking file handles, and it's probably more likely to be something inside PIL/Pillow, so I thought of delegating the file handling to the Standard Library and keeping PIL away from it.

So, instead of letting PIL open, read, close each image like you currently do:

- let Python open the file and read the data and close the file handle,
- wrap the data it reads in a BytesIO and let PIL read it from there without going near any file handles:

---

```
from io import BytesIO

# Let Python open the file, read the file, close the file and free the file-handle
with open('image.tif', 'rb') as f:
   data = f.read()

# Wrap the data from the file in a BytesIO and let PIL work on that
inMemoryTiff = BytesIO(data)

# Create a PIL Image by letting PIL read the BytesIO
im = Image.open(inMemoryTiff)
```